# is it possible to reduce delete code size with templates in C++

Tags: c++, nullptr

I have a lot of items, I am deleting. For each item, I am calling the following lines of related codes:

```
if (item) {
   delete item;
   item=nullptr;
}
```

so, instead, I am considering of using templates by defining a single function:

```
template <typename T>
void delete_it(T &item) {
    if (item) {
       delete item;
       item=nullptr;
    }
}
```

from this on, the following lines work fine:

```
delete_it(an_item);
delete_it(another_item);
```

I have checked it by allocating a character array dynamically and it seemed to work fine.
However, I haven't seen it used in anywhere. Is it an appropriate way of deleting?Is there a library(std for example) function doing just that? Thank you,

Comment: You should not be using `new` and `delete` anymore.  Without seeing what you are doing, I can't really suggest what you should be using, other then to say it should be an [RAII type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Comment: You can remove `if(item)`. Let me be first to suggest `delete std::exchange(item, nullptr)`. Right, use `std::unique_ptr`. The destructor does exactly the same as you do.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `if`, `delete item;
   item=nullptr;` is fine.

Comment: Note 2: use `std::unique_ptr` (probably, possibly some other smart pointer).

Comment: There's a pretty good chance you don't need dynamic allocation, or if you do, you could use a standard container to do it for you.

Comment: It is perfectly appropriate if that's what you find yourself doing a lot.  I have worked on codebases that had such a utility.  However, I usually found them not used so much as most such situations could better be replaced with a shared_ptr, unique_ptr, or something following the RAII pattern;. If you allocate an object in your constructor and delete it in your destructor, there is no need to worry about whether or not it is null.

Comment: It's unlikely to reduce compiled code size, since each different type being used results in a new instantiation of the template function.  And each time the function is called, the compiler will probably inline it.  And even if the compiler didn't, it's likely the overhead of a function call is significant vs the size of the function.  But it does reduce the code you have to write.  There's nothing wrong with it.  But like others have said, there are even better ways now.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  if (item) {
>        delete item;
> ```

The `if` here is useless. You don't need it.

> I have checked it by allocating a character array dynamically
>   ...
>   Is it an appropriate way of deleting?

`delete` is **not** an appropriate way of deleting a dynamic array created with `new[]`. Only `delete[]` is.

---

> I haven't seen it used in anywhere

`delete` is typically only used in the destructor of a RAII class. In such context, setting the pointer to null is redundant, because the pointer is about to stop existing. This is probably why you haven't seen what you're doing elsewhere.

Even further, best practice is to apply the single responsibility principle, and use a smart pointer or a container instead of new'ing and deleting manually. There is a standard container for dynamic arrays: `std::vector` as well as a standard container for character arrays that represent strings: `std::string`.

Bonus reminder: Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Comment: I am using new for example for the following cases and I don't know how it would be possible to use other std library functions:

    new std::thread(...);

Comment: @b.g. Why do you allocate the thread object dynamically? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: @b.g. instead of `std::thread * thread = new std::thread(...); /* some code */ delete thread;`, use `std::thread thread(...); /* some code */ `

Comment: @eerorika During initialization phase of my code, I create a thread from a function(which is a while loop) and to join it in the stop phase of my code, I need to destruct and join it. These (initialization and stop) procedures are in separate class methods, therefore I pass the thread as a class member variable. Therefore, I use it as a pointer. I am not sure if this is the wise approach however. I am open to suggestions. Thank you

Comment: @Caleth, I need to access the thread object inside different functions, therefore I have defined it as a member variable.

Comment: @b.g. Sounds like convoluted and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Type *item;
...
if (item) {
   delete item;
   item=nullptr;
}
```

With:

```
std::unique_ptr<Type> item;
...
item.reset();
```

For arrays:

```
std::vector<Type> items;
...
items.clear();
```